# How to resolve hint character wrapping on autosizing TextView with empty text on android?

Tags: android, textview

I want to use [autosizing `TextView`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/autosizing-textview) for dynamic `text` content.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical">
  <TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="350dp"
    android:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
    android:hint="hint"
    android:text="some dynamic text" />
</LinearLayout>
```

This works so far:

[image: text is not empty]

But there is an issue if the dynamic `text` content is empty. The `TextView` wraps each character of the `hint` content to a new line:

[image: text is empty]

I expect `hint` to behave like `text`. How to resolve this without hacks like setting `text` content to `hint` content if the former is empty.

Comment: If you get a solution to this please post it here

Answer (score 0):

The same event happened to me.

I defined this and it fixed it.

```
app:autoSizeStepGranularity="1dp"
```

I'd definitely set the minimum and maximum sizes together.

```
android:hint="no message"
app:autoSizeMaxTextSize="20sp"
app:autoSizeMinTextSize="1sp"
app:autoSizeStepGranularity="1sp"
app:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
```

Answer (score -1):

layout.xml

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     tools:context=".MainActivity">

   <TextView
      android:id="@+id/show"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="350dp"
      android:hint="no message"
      />
  </RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
        TextView  shows =  findViewById(R.id.show);

        TextViewCompat.setAutoSizeTextTypeWithDefaults(shows,
                TextViewCompat.AUTO_SIZE_TEXT_TYPE_UNIFORM);

        if(message.isEmpty()){

        shows.setWidth(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        }else{

        shows.setText(message);
        shows.setWidth(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

         }
```

if you add this code please run the code.

Comment: It is hard to imagine that setting the width of the `TextView` to a layout parma constant with value -2 will fix this issue. Did you test your recommendation at all? Well I did. As expected, it is not working. Regardless of this specific answer - next time you provide an answer, please do not just guess and provide some explanation and background information for your solution. This will gain you more positive votes on your answer and keep the quality of SO at a good level. [Have a look at this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).